# phpbb google cloud platform

Tags: google-app-engine, google-compute-engine, phpbb

I'd like to setup phpBB on Google Cloud Platform. Should I be using AppEngine ([example setup](http://fredsa.allen-sauer.com/2013/07/standing-up-phpbb-instance-on-google.html)), Compute Engine or Containers?

Comment: Nobody else will be able to answer that question except for you. It depends on how experienced you are with these technologies, what are your requirements for infrastructure customization, scaling, affordability, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I would say go with App Engine first, see if it works for you. If you need more flexibility, it should be easy to migrate to Compute Engine. Feel free to use Containers if you know what you're doing.